# Add "Skips" to Advanced Review Statistics

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, review-abuse

So on Code Review we currently have a rather wide margin of time that's used on close-vote reviews. The "slowest" user is averaging out at 180 seconds per review, the "fastest" is clocking in at 10.

This humungous discrepancy (basically an order of magnitude faster than the average) would make sense if the latter user reviewed only clear-cut cases (as is possible by skipping). Unfortunately the advanced review stats for the close queue (or any of the other queues) do not have any data on Skips.

Could we please have the skips displayed in the advanced review stats?